# vagrant port forwarding does not work without any error

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to set up my project into virtual machine so I can work with it from my host machine. I've set up port forwarding in vagrantfile and when I run 'vagrant up' everything is ok and there is no errors. But when I  try to access to my app in VM from host machine, I can't.
My vagrant file is realy simple:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 8001
  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/"

end
```

On start I get this:

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8001 => 4567 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

Looks like there is everything OK, but when I try to access to 127.0.0.1:4567 from my host (and I run my app in guest machine on 127.0.0.1:8001),  I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` err_code in browser.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work fine when you use `vagrant ssh` and then get site from local port 8001?

Comment: Yes, from guest machine I can get my app page with curl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'm sorry if it's not the case, i don't have reputation for comments.

Maybe your service is listening on **127.0.0.1** when it should be listening on **0.0.0.0**. You can check it running this command on the guest:

`netstat -lnptu | grep ':8001'`

At the fourth column you should get **0.0.0.0:8001**. If it's not the case, look for the binding option on the service you are running.

PS: If it's a Sinatra Server (what I'm guessing by the host port number) take a look at the **:bind** topic on this [page](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html).

Comment: I run my up on 0.0.0.0:8001 (it is django app, I used 8000 port, but looks like it is used by some other service) and now I can access it from host machine! Thanks!) Is this secure to run on 0.0.0.0 IP?

Comment: Don't worry! It's safe. Binding on 0.0.0.0 it's just a way to tell your service to listen on every interface you have and 127.0.0.1 is just one of those interfaces. If you want to know more about that see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost). By the way, you're welcome! Nice to know you've solved your problem.